# How to cleanly rebase large number of commits without changing my PR's files changed?

Tags: git, github

I have opened a pull request to a `repo` from my fork's branch `br`. while the pull request is in review, there are other developers who merged their pull requests and the upstream repo is updated. I updated my branch with the master using the update branch button [image: update button]

Now, I have a large number of commits and want to squash them into one. When I do `git rebase -i HEAD~21` I can squash all of them into a single commit, but they contain other changes from upstream master and mess up my actual changes. How do I do this cleanly?

Comment: With `rebase -i` you can also reorder commits. You can try grouping yours together and then squashing.

Comment: Linking your PR will be useful in inspecting what's happening. But generally, I'd just merge the upstream master with my branch. First, run `git checkout master`, then `git pull upstream master`. Now your local master is updated to match the remote upstream one. Then, `git checkout your_branch`, and finally `git merge master`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a `git rebase -i HEAD~21` I have an alternative workflow that will help solve some of your problems, and I’ll explain each step below.

`git checkout branch br`

`git pull`

This will ensure you have the latest version of the br branch.

`git checkout <your feature branch>`

`git rebase <br>`

This will reapply your commits on top of another base tip (the updated br branch in this case). This will make it so that all you have to worry about is your own commits and squashing them. If I remember correctly this is also the point at which you will be dealing with merge conflicts.

`git rebase -i <br>`

You know what to do from here. Squash or fix up as you would normally.

Since you performed a rebase you will of course need to do a `git push -f <origin yourbranch>` so make sure that your git log has what you want. You can use the reflog to roll back changes if you make mistakes here.